# How to wait 5 min in PHP without sleep

Tags: php, yii

I am using a function where two user reply there answers in different time interval .If 1st user has replyed how  to wait for another user reply in PHP where maximum wait time is 5 min. without using java script.

Comment: Going to have to use JavaScript. You can't do things like this Server-side.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Here i want to doing update 3rd field basis on two replies if 1st one is replay update  it value in database and for result of 3rd field how to wait that user's replay who not replay yet .maximum wait time is 5 min.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a cookie and have it expire in 5 minutes. 
If the cookie does not exit then proceed as normal.
If the cookie exists then ignore process